# Update innerhtml of element using viewchild in angular 2

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have html element like

```
<section class="" #hiddenElement>
    <span>title</span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</section>
```

I access the element in component using

```
@ViewChild('hiddenElement') hiddenElement: ElementRef;
```

How do i update the innerhtml of element whose class is value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `hiddenElement` [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) using `nativeElement.children`, filter them by className and modify their innerHTML using [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

Something like this

```
Array
    .from(this.hiddenElement.nativeElement.children)
    .filter(c => c.className.includes('value'))
    .forEach(c => c.innerHTML = 'New innerHTML');
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hbE5MbhKZaEROoHqpTEf?p=preview)