# Angular 4 read inner component html as string and process it then render back

Tags: angular

How to read inner html content as String of custom component ? and then process or modify it and then render on screen.

I googled found many ways to add custom HTML string and then render by using Angular compiler or binding as value like below

```
<div [innerHTML]="some_string"></div>
```

Link for  [How to translate HTML string to real HTML element by ng-for in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472297/how-to-translate-html-string-to-real-html-element-by-ng-for-in-angular-2)

But not able to understand, How to read as existing or provided inner HTML as string.

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Try take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668055/2375907) and let me know if it's what you need

Comment: For angular 4 questions you must set angular tag not angularjs

Comment: Thanks Kalamarico, didn't noticed that.

Comment: DrSatan1, Basically I  want to read all html as string which custom component has and then  I wan to add rows and columns dynamically based on provide configuration.So I don't think, it will help me directly.