# change content of <ng-template> programmatically from a component

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-template-variable

**EDITED**

i got reference to a  by a template variable in its component.

```
<ng-template #templateLogGroup>Logs Group</ng-template>

@ViewChild('templateLogGroup') templateLogGroup : TemplateRef<any>;
```

Now, how can i change the content dynamically in a method of the controller?

i'm trying to do in this way:
`this.templateLogGroup.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHtml = "<strong>changed<strong>";`

but on the screen nothing is changed.

On the other hand, if i print to the console the content of "templateLogGroup" i can notice that the conthent of `templateLogGroup.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHtml` is changed.

So seems that this operation doesn't fire the rendering

this is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/github/pinale/changetemplatecontent

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667715/update-innerhtml-of-element-using-viewchild-in-angular-2 .   Also read about componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory

Comment: You need to provide more detail to suggest best approach in your case.

Comment: What kind of content? And why can't it be solved with `*ngIf` `*ngFor` or routing?

Comment: @Shashank Vivek it's a step further

Comment: @Mike S simple html, i need to change the content when someone click on a "step"  of a "material stepper", so using *ngIf or *ngFor is too complicated for me without changing the setup i've

Comment: You will need to sanitize the html before using it in a template. That said, I still wonder if you can't just use different templates for your "steps". If they are generated dynamically, then of course it's a little more complicated.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubveqw is this close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @MikeS. it seems just what i need but my code doesn't work as expected, i've provided a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/pinale/changetemplatecontent

Comment: [Forked from your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kcb2dv) . Angular seems to not update the view after you set the innerHtml. This works, but it uses a binding to the innerHtml of your div element.